# check/uncheck checkbox to show/hide an input file element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to show and hide an input file element on check/uncheck of a checkbox using javascript. I want to check checkbox c to hide the input file and uncheck it to show the input file. For the others checkboxes, it must be shown. What is the best way to implement this? what I'm doing wrong in my code? I am open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance.

My html code is:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><b>  A:</br>

                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a"  id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Aa</label></br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Ab</label>
                    </b></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><b>  B: </br>

                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Ba</label></br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Bb</label>
                    </b></label></br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><b>  C: </br>

                <label><input type="checkbox"  name="c" value="c" id="hide_id" onclick="showHide()">   C </label></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and that what i'm trying to show and hide by clicking( to hide) on checkbox  c and unclick it again(to show) is this below sothat it can be visible for the others 4 checkbox again:

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
<label id="visible" name="hidden"><b> files: </b></label></br>
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="hidden" id="visible"/> </br>
   </div>
```

i tried this in JS:

```
 function showHide() {


    var checkbox_A_B = document.getElementById("show_id");
    var checkbox_C = document.getElementById("hide_id");

    var hiddenBrowserFiles = document.getElementsByName("hidden");
    var visibleBrowserFiles = document.getElementById("visible");

    for(var i = 0; i < hiddenBrowserFiles.length; i++)
    {
        if(checkbox_C.checked)
        {
            hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        else
        {
            visibleBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "block";
        }

        if(checkbox_A_B.checked)
        {
            visibleBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "block";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: first, you are only manipulating "**label**" and not file. And there is one checkbox or multiple checkboxes for each file. If only one checkbox 'C' is there, then your logic is bit absurd

Comment: your ''**visibleBrowserFiles**" is undefined in your case. Also you are using name and ids very confusing

Comment: As i said before i am new to javascript or html code. i've multiple checkboxes as you can see in my html code. thank a lot your code help me

Comment: try to keep one id and its name unique (not like visible, hidden), also try to avoid names. Any other help you need regarding this?

Comment: @ Gaurav Chaudhary i'am just trying to find a way to do sothat one of checkbox of a groupe A or B can be checked not the both at the same time. Any suggestion? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

1. `id` is unique .so try with function with `this`.
2. So to check with id name and apply the condition .
3. its `show id` only with `block`
4. its `hide_id` apply with check and an uncheck condition

```js
function showHide(that) {
  var hiddenBrowserFiles = document.getElementsByName("hidden");

  for (var i = 0; i < hiddenBrowserFiles.length; i++) {
    if (that.id == 'show_id') {
      if (that.checked) {
        hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "show";
      } 
}
else{
      if (that.checked) {
        hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "none";
      } 
      else{
       hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "block";
      }
}
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><b>  A:</br>

                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a"  id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Aa</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Ab</label>
      </b>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><b>  B: </br>

                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Ba</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Bb</label>
      </br>
      </label>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><b>  C: </br>

                <label><input type="checkbox"  name="c" value="c" id="hide_id" onclick="showHide(this)">   C </label></b>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group col-xs-8">
  <label id="visible" name="hidden"><b> files: </b></label></br>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="hidden" id="visible" /> </br>
</div>
```

For more simplified version .single line `if condition`

```
function showHide(that) {
  var hiddenBrowserFiles = document.getElementsByName("hidden");

  for (var i = 0; i < hiddenBrowserFiles.length; i++) {
    hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = (that.id == 'show_id') ? (that.checked) ? "show" : '' : (that.checked) ? 'none' : 'block';

  }
}
```

***updated answer with*** [`radio button`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

```js
function showHide(that) {
  var hiddenBrowserFiles = document.getElementsByName("hidden");

  for (var i = 0; i < hiddenBrowserFiles.length; i++) {
    if (that.id == 'show_id') {
      if (that.checked) {
        hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "show";
      }
    } else {
      if (that.checked) {
        hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        hiddenBrowserFiles[i].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><b>  A:</br>

                           <label><input type="radio" name="a" value="a"  id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Aa</label></br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="a" value="a" id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Ab</label>
      </b>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><b>  B: </br>

                           <label><input type="radio" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Ba</label></br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide(this)">  Bb</label>
      </br>
      </label>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><b>  C: </br>

                    <label><input type="checkbox"  name="c" value="c" id="hide_id" onclick="showHide(this)">   C </label></b>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group col-xs-8">
  <label id="visible" name="hidden"><b> files: </b></label></br>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="hidden" id="visible" /> </br>
</div>
```

Comment: I also try yours and it works perfectly for me. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @R.Van also see the simplified version of the if condition refer the updated answer

Comment: @ prasad great thank you!!! one more question: is it a way to do sothat one of checkbox of a groupe A or B can be checked not the both at the same time? it'll be very cool

Comment: @R.Van .you need ah radio button .see my updated answer

Comment: Thank again!!! I did it before with the radiobuttons but I thought it would also be possible with the checkbox, from where my question. I notice that the radiobutton does not allow to check and uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showHide() {
    var checkbox_A_B = document.getElementById("show_id");
    var checkbox_C = document.getElementById("hide_id");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        if(checkbox_C.checked)
        {
           fileInput.style.display = "none";
        }
        else
        {
            fileInput.style.display = "block";
        }

        if(checkbox_A_B.checked)
        {
           fileInput.style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><b>  A:</br>

                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a"  id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Aa</label></br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Ab</label>
                    </b></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><b>  B: </br>

                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Ba</label></br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" id="show_id" onclick="showHide()">  Bb</label>
                    </b></label></br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><b>  C: </br>

                <label><input type="checkbox"  name="c" value="c" id="hide_id" onclick="showHide()">   C </label></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-8">
  <div id="fileInput">
    <label id="visible" ><b> files: </b></label></br>
    <input class="form-control" type="file"/> </br>
  </div>
</div>
```